# How to write REST Web services in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating api for mobile app in laravel 5.2 version but now I am facing one problem. Problem is that in my **routes.php** I am created routes for my website. Now my question is if I start creating api for mobile for that I have to create new routes for mobile api Or I can use same routes for RESTapi also?
In Laravel 5.2 I have to add any webservices libraries or not? If yes, Please suggest me how to use RESTapi in Laravel 5.2? Please help.

My routes.php

```
Route::auth();    
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('admin/users', 'UserController@getUsers');
Route::get('admin/users/add', 'UserController@addUser');
```

Comment: Have a look at laravel resource controllers https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You have different middleware in laravel. By default you should have "web" middleware activated. It is either directly in your routes.php, in your controler constructor OR in the RouteServiceProvider.php

You wouldn't use web middleware for an api / restful service, therefore you should use another middleware ( e.g. "api" middleware which throttles requests to only allow max. 60 requets per minute etc. )

Typically you group your api requests

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function()
{
...
}
```

to strictly divide them from your application. You can then also easy change to v2 for example if you plan many releases

**Update**

if your api logic follows your business logic then you could aswell just watch for ajax calls and return json

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    // do stuff here
    if($request->ajax()) {
       // return json
    }

    // return view
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank for quick reply of my question.
In my routes i am not using middleware

Comment: Are you sure, did you check the routeserviceprovider?

Comment: As said, check your RouteServiceprovider and look for protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router) ( at least for me here is defined that all routes in routes.php use web middleware)

Answer (score 0):

If your routes an their inside logic returns json response, Its not necessary to create new routes, But if your routes does not returns json response, you must write new routes. 
For having better APIs, [json-hal](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), [jsend](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) or [json-api](http://jsonapi.org) conventions may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your api routes can coexist with your regular web routes. It's customary, however, to separate them, typically by a subdomain (https://api.yoursite.com), or at least a path (https://yoursite.com/api/v1). 
Also, api version number is often included, as in my last example.

As for a package to develop apis in Laravel, have a look at [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api). It's very complete, provides its own router, versioning, security, etc.